Configuration to ElasticSearch and Serilog dont work in .NET 8
I have configured log sending to ElasticSearch/Kibana with .NET 8, using the following packages:
Serilog.AspNetCore
Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch
Serilog.Sinks.Async
Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch
Elastic.CommonSchema
Elastic.CommonSchema.Serilog

I try of two methods (the active and what is commented):
public static void AddElasticSearchSerilog(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    var elasticUri = builder.Configuration["ElasticSearch:Url"];
    var index = builder.Configuration["ElasticSearch:Index"];
    ElasticsearchSinkOptions options = new(new Uri(elasticUri!))
    {
        AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
        IndexFormat = $"{index}{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy.MM.dd}",
        AutoRegisterTemplateVersion = AutoRegisterTemplateVersion.ESv7,
        CustomFormatter = new EcsTextFormatter()
    };

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(options)
        .CreateLogger();

    //builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostBuilder, loggerConfiguration) =>
    //{
    //    loggerConfiguration
    //        .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostBuilder.Configuration)
    //        .WriteTo.Console(new EcsTextFormatter())
    //        .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(options)
    //        .WriteTo.Debug()
    //        .WriteTo.File("logs/log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day); ;
    //});
}

And in my class Program:
builder.AddElasticSearchSerilog();

var app = builder.Build();

var logger = app.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
logger.LogInformation("The application is starting...");

I setup this log for testing...
In my appsettings.json I using:
"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Serilog": "Debug"
    }
  }
},
  "ElasticSearch": {
    "Url": "http://localhost:9200",
    "Index": "logs-api-dev-"
}

When I start the application, the logs appear in the console, but they don’t show up in Kibana.
First, I created an Index pattern:
picture
My index pattern name matched with 6 sources.. which means that in some way the application managed to "create" the indexes, right?
In time field, selected "@timestamp".
However, when I go to Kibana > Discover, select the created index, I see this message:
picture
I tried to create an log manually with Postman yesterday and it appear:
picture
But nothing sent by my api appears... Why?

Do you try to custom the timerange in "advanced settings"?

No.. where? I change the timerange, I used "last 15 minutes", "last year", "last 5 years" and until future dates

I managed to solve it.. first included logs in send for elastic, because my application was not sending. Then show problem with creating template, and after, show this error "only write ops with an op_type of create are allowed in data stream", but I dont used data stream.
Then I discovered that the problem was the index I was using. I used index prefix "logs-api-" that possibly conflicts with some index already created by elastic associated with the data stream.
Changing the index prefix, resolved the problem.
"ElasticSearch": {
    "Url": "http://localhost:9200",
    "Index": "myapp-dev-"
}

